# Host Nuget Gallery V3 API on IIS

Tags: nuget

I would like to create my own nuget gallery with API V3 on IIS.
I've intalled gallery from this git repo: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery

However - this is api v2 version.
Where I can find v3 version?

Cheers

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Dave Glick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/nuget-api-v3) posts and the links provided?

Comment: Yes. However, there is a description of v3 libraries. I would like to get nuget gallery with v3 api version.

Comment: do you mean a nuget gallery or a nuget server? they are two different things....

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the V3 API is not supported. There are several places in the source code that [suggest](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=v3%20extension%3Aconfig&type=) it is.